# Firefox tab keep loading with an iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, iframe

I've added an iframe into an HTML page, that I'm testing on **Firefox Developer**.

The presence of the iframe causes the parent page to keep loading : the loading circle in the tab don't stop. After a few minutes, it seems to degrade the performances.
**No problem on Google Chrome.**

The iframe doesn't point to a file. This is at first an empty iframe, that I complete with HTML picked from an AJAX request (I'm trying to show the body of an e-mail inside an iframe).
I don't think this has an influence, but I'm using AngularJS on the page.

I've tried to comment every interaction with javascript on the iframe, but the issue is still here.
I've also tried to point to a real file (an empty file).

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-same-origin" class="p-y" width="100%" ng-init="resizeFrame()"></iframe>
```

(Added a sandbox attribute, in case of origin issue, but, doesn't change anything)

What's the problem ? And how can I resolve it ?

Comment: is it mandatory to use an iframe ? Sometimes (often) iframe is a bad idea...

Comment: I don't know how I could do it in a different way...
Problem is... the email body I receive is full HTML document (inculdes <html>, <head>...). So I have to isolate that part of the code in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

To display dynamic data inside your page you could use a simple [div] tag.

You define an empty tag

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

and when your AJAX call return with success, you can inject your HTML into the div

```
function getData(){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "<b>Sender :</b> abc@heart.com<br/><b>Subject :</b> Hello world";
}
```

[Here you can find a jsfiddle running sample](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/ngnrards/) (I've no AJAX call but simulate it with a javascript function)

**UPDATE (after comment update)**

Setting innerHTML, headers are discarded, I've [updated jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/ngnrards/1/) and you can try, into div are added only contents